# Search of integer is slow when comapared to string in solr

Tags: search, solr, cloudera

I have file which has integers and strings delimited by pipe like below

```html
abc|182|2rt|jd
yre|123|7yd|op
ifs|132|24d|oe
```

i have created a new field type pipedelimited as below

```html
<fieldType name="pipedelimited" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
         <analyzer>
             <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="|"/>
             <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

The problem is when i search for a integer the search will take too much of time to respond,
but if i search for string response is in millisecond.

Please help with the reason for this

Comment: Can you give the example of both types of queries?

Comment: Thank you for response.. i  am using query http://ip:8983/solr/research3/select?q=rawdata:"CANADA" which gave response in 0.3 sec but when i use same query for integer it takes more then 2 sec to respond

Comment: What's the INTEGER query looks like? You need to give a bit more information. Solr should NOT be slower, so you need to provide as much information/changes as possible if you hope for a good answer.

Comment: solr query for integer is:  ip:8983/solr/research3/select?q=rawdata:"00902342443" ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your search examples are text as far as Solr is concerned. So, they should be treated identically.

So, either you missed something from your description of the situation or there is something very funny about particular records. Have you tried searching for string and "integer" values that supposed to return the same record. Do you get the same speed? You should.

Try using a debug flag and see what you can notice differently.

Basically, side by side comparisons should be evaluated by trying to make all other parameters as equal as possible. And then focusing on the visible differences.